# Static method on a static class, is this method thread safe?

Tags: c#, static, thread-safety

Do I need to use the lock (createPaletteLocker)? I'm using it because I think that doing so I can avoid a write to ColorPaletteHandle.palettesList[type] while other thread is reading it.

EDIT 1: The dictionary is set only at the static constructor. So it I'll not be changed (add/remove) anymore, but the stances that it holds will change from null to the respective created palette.

```
public static class ColorPaletteHandle
{
    private static readonly object createPaletteLocker = new object();
    private static Dictionary<ColorPaletteType, ColorPalette> palettesList = null;

    static ColorPaletteHandle()
    {
        palettesList = new Dictionary<ColorPaletteType, ColorPalette>();
        palettesList.Add(ColorPaletteType.Default, ColorPaletteHandle.defaultPalette);
        palettesList.Add(ColorPaletteType.EdgesHighlight, ColorPaletteHandle.edgesHighlight);
        palettesList.Add(ColorPaletteType.GrayScale, ColorPaletteHandle.grayScale);
        palettesList.Add(ColorPaletteType.HeatMap, ColorPaletteHandle.heatMap);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a palette.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ColorPalette GetPalette(ColorPaletteType type)
    {
        ColorPalette pal = null;
        lock (ColorPaletteHandle.createPaletteLocker)
        {
            pal = ColorPaletteHandle.palettesList[type];
            if (pal == null)
            {
                ColorPaletteHandle.palettesList[type] = ColorPaletteHandle.CreatePalette(type);
                pal = ColorPaletteHandle.palettesList[type];
            }
        }
        return pal;
    }

   //stuff...
   }
```

Comment: Looks like standard single-check locking to me.  Without it you could get into trouble if there are multiple threads the first time a given type is accessed.

Comment: @ebyrob It could also [potentially] break if you were trying to add two new values at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this method is thread safe since only one thread can modify `palettesList` at a time, and yes, you do need the lock if you intend on using `Dictionary`

But, if you are on .NET 4 or above, [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) would be better suited for this

Comment: You didn't seem to answer the actual question he asked, "Do I need to use the lock (createPaletteLocker)?"

Comment: @Servy didn't see the "second part" of the question, I saw the question as "Static method on a static class, is this method thread safe?"  :)

Comment: Thank you both. I think I'll keep the lock, because the class wont change the number of itens of the dictionary, so I dont need to use the ConcurrentDictionary. But thanks for pointing it, I was not aware of it.

Answer (score 6):

The `Dictionary` class is not designed to be accessed from multiple threads.  Doing so would indeed cause problems unless you synchronized access.  With the `lock` statement the method is fine, without it it is not.

Even better than using `lock` would be to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead.  It is a dictionary that is specifically designed to be used from multiple threads at the same time.  You'd be able to refactor your whole method to one call to `GetOrAdd`.